# Reporting Services 2005 Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ftp, subscriptions

I am trying to send reports from Reporting Services 2005 by to an FTP location but this does not seem to be an option within the subscription settings. Is this possible to have done?

Comment: Somewhat I have a couple subscriptions that go out via email and those users have asked that I send the report directly to their FTP site but I am not seeing within my reporting services exactly where I even start to set that up????

Answer (score 2):

There are third party tools for things like this:
http://www.christiansteven.com/products/sql-rd/

If buying something is not an option, you can create a process that FTPs after you drop the report.

Comment: So where do you go within reporting services to Create a Process?

Comment: I think he means to write a small program to do this. It wouldn't be horrible, the Reporting Services web services does all of the heavy lifting.

Comment: So where do you start this process of writing a program within visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can code your own custom extension to SSRS to "send" reports directly to file or even to a printer from a subscription. The are samples provided by MS that show you how to do both if you don't mind getting into some code (I think they have examples for VB and C#) and XML config files.

I've implemented the printing extension before, very handy.

Sorry it's taken so long for my suggestion, been in other kinds of development lately.

HTH